# system is computationally singular using mtsdi for data imputation in R

Tags: r, imputation, arima

I am trying to run an imputation on my missing data in R using the mtsdi package. I am trying to compare the performance of imputation between the 3 models -> splines, arima and gam.

The splines method works for me but when I am trying the same approach with arima it throws a "system is computationally singular" error.

I am using the same data and I have cheated slightly in my arima model by specifying all the arima models to 1,0,0. I plan to change this later.

Could this be the reason for the error?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxgkBr1CkDf7WktPdnhEMDNsQTg/view?usp=sharing) is a dput (Imputation_Test) of my data and below is the code I am using for the splines and arima models.

Imputation_Test <- ts(Imputation_Test,frequency = 96)

```
variable2bImputed <- ~KD0027U09A3+KD0027U09C3+KD0046U09A3+KD0046U09C3+KD0103U09B3+KD0103U09C3+KD0166U09C3+KD0177U09C3+LX0017U09B3+LX0022U09A3+LX0022U09B3+LX0022U09C3+LX0023U09A3+LX0023U09B3+LX0060U09A3+LX0060U09B3+LX0060U09C3+LX0073U09A3+LX0074U09A3+LX0074U09B3+LX0074U09C3+LX0079U09A3+LX0080U09A3+LX0080U09B3+LX0080U09C3+LX0088U09A3+LX0088U09B3+LX0088U09C3+OF0028U09B3+OF0061U09B3+KD0056U09A3+KK0125U09A3+LX0017U09A3+LX0017U09C3+LX0025U09A3+LX0096U09A3+LX0097U09A3+Modified

imputed.spline <- mnimput(variable2bImputed,
                          Imputation_Test,
                          eps=1e-3,
                          ts=TRUE,
                          method="spline")

arcontrol<-list(order=cbind(c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0),c(1,0,0)), period=NULL)
imputed.arima <- mnimput(variable2bImputed,
                          Imputation_Test,
                          eps=1e-3,
                          ts=TRUE,
                          method="arima",
                       ar.control = arcontrol)
```